# Can the "Picture Library Slideshow" web part have a relative link to picture library?

Tags: 2013, picture-library

I have a site template with a Picture library slideshow web part connected to a picture library called "Dashboard Pictures".

I saved this site as a template and created a new site only to find that it isn't linked with the current "Dashboard Pictures" picture library. The web part looks like this:

[image]

If I edit the page, then edit the slideshow web part and click on 'OK' the library links again.

The problem is we don't want users to have to do the extra clicks.

Is there a way to make the link to the picture library in the slideshow relative to the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no, there is no possibility to specify the relative Url for Picture Library.   [Picture Library Slideshow web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.picturelibraryslideshowwebpart.aspx) exposes the following properties to query pictures from  Picture Library:

- [LibraryGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.picturelibraryslideshowwebpart.libraryguid.aspx) - unique identifier (GUID) of the picture library
- [ViewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.picturelibraryslideshowwebpart.viewguid.aspx) - GUID of the list view in the picture library.

---

These web part properties could be specified during site provisioning, for example using feature activation.

Comment: That is what I thought....but just wanted to make sure.  Thank you for the extra info.  I will have to try the feature way.

Comment: Unfortunately Picture Library Slideshow web part is very limited for configuration, basically the following properties could be specified only:
1)Layout
2)Speed
3)Picture library source (List and View Guids)
And closed to customization (no Xsl based). For example, there is no way to specify full-sized pictures for displaying or display additional properties.    


You could find some details in my blog regarding possible ways of customization of this web part: http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/04/27/beyond-the-slideshow-web-part-capabilities-in-sharepoint-2010/